# Autolayout UIImageview Swift

Tags: ios, uiimageview

So,

I am trying to build an app from design, the design consists of 3 images horizontally on a portrait layout

Supporting Iphone 5 and upwards.

From this guide `http://iosdesign.ivomynttinen.com/` the Iphone 5 should have 640px of horizontal space.

Each image is 100px by 148px high, therefore I have created added 3x UIImageview and laid them out horizontally.

Now without any constraints I get the following

[image]

If I auto constrain I get the following, same if I add constraints manually

[image]

Skips out the middle.

If I go to any any constraint , I get an error message in the logger.

This can be a vertical space to top layout constraint, just the one and it breaks.

I assume as images are only 100px wide, I should have plenty of room.

On the UIImageview I have done the following

Set Height and Width

Content is AspectFit

Clip Subviews Selected

Auto re-size selected

I have either not understood App design and the images do not fit, or have done some incorrectly with IB and UIImageview?

Any thoughts on this.

Sorry not a lot of code as it's all Interface builder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

My own fault, "reset to auto constraints" and "clear constraints" had a bit of an issue, there was a bunch of constraints still kicking about when I delved in deeper.

In the end deleted then all and then manually added.